# Can the number of terms of sequence $p_1$, $2p_1+1$, $2(2p_1+1)+1$, . . . be more than 3?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Can the number of terms of sequence $p_1$, $2p_1+1$, $2(2p_1+1)+1$, . . . be  more than 3? Where all terms are prime.

For primes $p_1\equiv 1 mod 3$ we have:

$2p_1+1\equiv (2+1) mod 3 \equiv 0 mod 3$

So eligible primes to produce new primes must be of the form $3k-1$ such that:

$p_1\equiv -1 mod 3$  ⇒ $p_2=2p_1+1 \equiv (-2+1=-1) mod 3$

⇒ $p_3=2(2p_2)+1\equiv -1 mod 3$

And it will give numbers $p_n\equiv -1 mod 3$ if we continue.

So we expect number of terms  being prime not limited.But I could not find number of terms more than 3. here are some examples:

$p_1=11$ ⇒$p_2=2\times 11+1=23$  ⇒ $p_3=2\times 23+1=47$ $p_4=2\times 47=95$

$p_1=41$ ⇒$p_2=2\times 41+1=83$ ⇒$2\times 83+1=167$ ⇒$2\times 167+1=235$

My conjecture is that the number of terms of such sequence can not be more than 3, Can some one gives a counter example?

Comment: $5, 11, 23, 47$? They are related to [Sophie-Germain/Safe Primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_and_Sophie_Germain_primes) and [Cunningham Chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cunningham_chain).

Comment: Please do not edit your question in such a way that invalidates answers after they have been provided.  Instead, if you have another question, use the "Ask Question" button to ask that question.

Comment: The very first prime already provides a counterexample: $2$, $5$, $11$, $23$, $47$.

Answer (score 5):

Define sequence $\{p_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ as follows: $p_1=q$ where $q$ is some prime number and $p_{n+1}=2p_n+1$ for $n\geq 1$. The question is whether there is a prime $q$ such that all $p_n$ are prime numbers (for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$). We claim that there is no such $q$.

Suppose the contrary. Firstly, we will obtain explicit formula for $p_n$. Indeed, note that $p_{n+1}+1=2(p_n+1)$ for $n\geq 1$, so
$$
p_{n+1}+1=2(p_n+1)=2^2(p_{n-1}+1)=\ldots=2^n(p_1+1)=(q+1)\cdot 2^n.
$$
Hence, $p_{n}=(q+1)\cdot 2^{n-1}-1$ for $n\geq 1$.

Now if $q>2$, we will consider $p_{q}$. Note that
$$
p_{q}=(q+1)\cdot 2^{q-1}-1\equiv 2^{q-1}-1\equiv 0\pmod q
$$
due to Fermat's Little Theorem. However, $p_q$ is prime, so $p_q=q$ but this impossible because $q>1$.

It remains to consider case $q=2$. In this case, $p_n=3\cdot 2^{n-1}-1$, so $p_6=3\cdot 32-1=95=5\cdot 19$ is not prime.

Thus, there is no such $q$ and such a sequence cannot be infinite.

Comment: Minor error:  the sequence for $q = 2$ goes $2, 5, 11, 23, 47, 95, \dots$; there's no 25.

Comment: Thanks, edited.

Answer (score 3):

The previous question was can the number of terms in the sequence be more than $3$:

The comment has answered the question by giving an example.

Out of curiosity, I have written a simple code to print out some of such sequences:

```
import math
def checkprime(num):
    if num > 1:
       for i in range(2,int(math.sqrt(num))+1):
           if (num % i) == 0:
               return False
               break
       else:
          return True
        

print([2, 5, 11, 23, 47])
print([5, 11, 23, 47])
for i in range(29, 10000,30):
    tmp = []
    j = i
    while checkprime(j):
        tmp.append(j)
        j = 2*j + 1
    if len(tmp) > 3:
        print(tmp)
```

Here are some of the prime sequences satisfying the condition:

```
[2, 5, 11, 23, 47]
[5, 11, 23, 47]
[89, 179, 359, 719, 1439, 2879]
[179, 359, 719, 1439, 2879]
[359, 719, 1439, 2879]
[509, 1019, 2039, 4079]
[1229, 2459, 4919, 9839]
[1409, 2819, 5639, 11279]
[2699, 5399, 10799, 21599]
[3539, 7079, 14159, 28319]
[6449, 12899, 25799, 51599]
```

Comment: Note that primes ending in the digits $1,3,7$ necessarily start a chain that yields a number ending in $5$, which is not prime and terminates the chain. Longer chains are possible only for primes ending in the digit $9$.

Comment: thanks for the input, from the chinese remainder theorem, besides the chain starting from $2$ and $5$, the rest must begins with $29 \pmod{30}$ then.